# Is there a program that will let me move an item from my Dock to my Menu Bar?

Tags: dock, menu-bar

And I don't mean like StatusDock, which will move it to the menu bar but also keeps it in the dock. I'd prefer it to just be gone from the Dock. Any way you can do this?

Comment: why not StatusDuck with hide dock?

Answer (score 3):

### Removing the Dock Icon

There is a way to remove the icon from the dock; the only problem is that you also lose the menu for the application, which is a slight drawback depending on the purpose of the application itself.

I, personally have never tried **StatusDuck**, perhaps when combined with the removal of the dock icon, it could be exactly what you're looking for.

As far as **removing the dock icon** itself, here's the process.

1. Find the application in the `Applications` folder (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + `click` **Dock Icon**)
2. `Right-click` application
3. Click `Show Package Contents`
4. Edit the `Info.plist` inside the `Contents` folder
5. Modify/Add the `LSUIElement` key so that the value says `YES`

**Note**: `LSUIElement` may change to `Application is agent (UIElement)`

If you would like the application to **show** the dock icon again, modify the value to `NO` and save the `.plist` file.

[image: Info.plist]

---

It is worthy to mention that using an application like **StatusDuck** could help you access the application as a status item. You will just have to test it out.

**StatusDuck:**
http://www.statusduck.com

Comment: I tried to do this but now whenever I try to open the application it just errors out. Not sure why adding the `Application is agent (UIElement)` to true would do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a way to change a Dock based app to a Menu Bar app, you are out of luck. But if you are looking for an alternative way to deal with apps focused on the Menu Bar there maybe a solution.

Take a look at [XMenu](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html) (Scroll to the bottom of the page.)

XMenu acts as a launcher for apps, folders, documents, etc. It will allow you to recreate something like the Apple Menu of the Classic Mac OS.

You may know the following, but worth restating:

- Non-running apps in the Dock can be removed by dragging the icon out of the Dock until a "Remove" popup appears over the icon. (This is the current behavior in Mac OS X 10.10)
- The Dock preferences allow you to hide the Dock so that it is mostly out of the way.
- Many utility type apps have a preference setting to change them from running in the Dock to the Menu Bar

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I do know that I can remove unopened apps from the dock. However, I like to keep my dock minimal, especially during work hours. Just things like me IDE, chats, email, notes, etc. However, certain apps like my money management app or my weather app (which stupidly only comes in dock form) are nice to have open and available without cluttering my dock. They'd be much more useful in the menu bar. That's what I'm trying to achieve.